# Obtaining current Record Id from quick actions button

Tags: visualforce, quickaction

In my current org, I have a quick action in the order object, that collect the data of the current order and generates a PDF with the data of that order. The org is entirely in Lightning Experience.

But, the code isn't getting the RecordId properly, the string 'param_recordId' is returning null.

The code:

```
private final Order Quote;
    
    public String renderAs {get;set;}
    public String contentType {get;set;}
    public List<OrderItem> QuoteItem {get;set;}
    public QuotePDF() {
        String param_renderAs = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('renderAs');
        String param_recordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        //block to obtain some fields of the referred order.
```

what I need to do to the class retrieve the current Id from the page where I'm hitting the quick action button?

Comment: is this quickaction associated to a VF page/controller?  if so, you'd get the OrderId from the standardController's `getId()` method

Comment: Yes, it is!! I got it with getId() method. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a VF page/controller on a standard object associated to the quickaction, then you can get the record ID as follows:

```
public class MyController {
   
   ApexPages.StandardController ctrl;
   Id orderId {
      get {return this.ctrl.getId();} set;
   }
   public Order myOrder {
     get {return [SELECT ... FROM Order WHERE id = :this.orderId];} set;
   } 

   public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {this.ctrl = ctrl;}
}
```

Note the use of properties to fetch values when needed leaving the constructor at its absolute most basic. Adapt as required for your application.